# Python is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: python, cmd

even though i have added the path variable i am unable to run the command

cmd [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfi7U.png)

path variable
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daf87.png)

Comment: I have also added the file in system32

Comment: You should check out this question and all the answers: https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path

Comment: Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are with the same cmd window, it will not get the system variable, you need to restart the cmd. just close and open another one